# Dropwizard Error 405 HTTP method POST Json

Tags: java, json, rest, dropwizard

So, I got this Web service application with Dropwizard. Here is the simple post method:

```
@Path(OmniURL.USERPATH)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UserResource {
    private final UserMobileDao userMobileDao;

public UserResource(UserMobileDao userMobileDao) {
    this.userMobileDao = userMobileDao;
}
@POST
@UnitOfWork
public UserMobile createUserMobile(UserMobile userMobile) {
    userMobile.setCreationDate(new Date()); 
    return userMobileDao.save(userMobile);
    }
}
```

This is the Json which I'm trying to POST from an android aplication: ( Recently I'm posting by the Postman application, returns the same error, and his ContentType is correctly setted 'application/json' as header)

```
{"creationDate":null,"email":"dutfp@hotmail.com","facebookProfile":{"email":"dutfp@hotmail.com","id":"679284068825262"},"id":null,"name":"Jack Et","onlineStoreUser":null}
```

This represents this entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_mobile")
public class UserMobile implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -273822158021109237L;
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_user_mobile", sequenceName = "seq_user_mobile", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_user_mobile")
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "email", length=30, nullable=false)
    private String email;
    @OneToOne(optional=true)
    private FacebookProfile facebookProfile;
    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    private Date creationDate;
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,optional=true)
    private OnlineStoreUser onlineStoreUser;
    @Column(name = "name", length=30, nullable=false)
    private String name;

    ....getters and setters
}
```

I've already try CORS settings like:

```
  /* e.servlets().addFilter("cors-filter", CrossOriginFilter.class)
    .addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST), true, "/*");
    */
   Dynamic filter = e.servlets().addFilter("CORS", CrossOriginFilter.class);
    filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), true, "/*");
    filter.setInitParameter("allowedOrigins", "*");
    filter.setInitParameter("allowedHeaders", "Content-Type,Authorization,X-Requested-With,Content-Length,Accept,Origin");
    filter.setInitParameter("allowedMethods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
    //filter.setInitParameter("preflightMaxAge", "5184000"); // 2 months
    filter.setInitParameter("allowCredentials", "true");
```

And no success...

The funny thing is that before a create all the entities, with their attributes, i've done a test of UserMobile with name and email and it worked well. So I believe it's a simple and stupid mistake of mine.

Comment: Are you sure your client is actually POSTing? An HTTP 405 error indicates that the client is attempting to GET or PUT etc. This is not related to the Content-Type. I'm not too familiar with the CORS filter, but have you tried disabling it altogether?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that i'm POSTing on client. About the CORS I've already tried let just that commented code above and no using CORS filters at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it is impossible to people here solve it. There is no information enough.

I've this settings from Dropwizard:

```
@Override
    public void initialize(Bootstrap<OmnichannelConfiguration> btstrp) {
        btstrp.addBundle(new ConfiguredAssetsBundle("/banana", "/banana"));
        btstrp.addBundle(hibernateBundle);
    }
```

And I realy don't know why I use it. I got from another project. :P

And my path up there is:

```
@Path(OmniURL.USERPATH)
```

Which OmniURL.USERPATH is "/banana/user"

So they can't be the same path, I changed ConfiguredAssetsBundle and is working.
"simple and stupid mistake of mine"